# iOS App is not suspending

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, multitasking

I have made a simple iOS app using Sprite Kit and have put it onto my iPhone. The app works perfectly fine however whenever you leave the app and then go back into it, it is not resuming the code but instead restarting it. Most apps that i have seen always go back to where you were if you leave and go back in, without removing from multitasking bar. Maybe suspend isn't the right word...I think that i should do something in my app delegate in the

```
    - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
    {
// Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
// Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }
```

however i don't know how to use it.

Comment: That could be a possibility however when i run it in the iOS simulator it seems to suspend perfectly fine. How would i be able to tell if it crashes when it is suspended?

Comment: check this tutorial for sprite kit. [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/49625/sprite-kit-tutorial-space-shooter)

Answer (score 0):

SpriteKit should pause automatically, but in case it doesn't add this to your `applicationWillResignActive:` method:

```
SKView *view = (SKView*)self.window.rootViewController.view;
view.paused = YES;
```

And in your `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method:

```
SKView *view = (SKView*)self.window.rootViewController.view;
view.paused = NO;
```